# Group and aggregate dataset in spark scala without using spark.sql()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset with account information of customers as below

| customerID | accountID | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | ACC001 | 20 |
| ID002 | ACC002 | 400 |
| ID003 | ACC003 | 500 |
| ID002 | ACC004 | 30 |

I want to groupby and aggregrate the above data to get output as below without using spark.sql functions, instead allowed to use datasets API

| accounts | number of accounts | totalBalance | averageBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ID001,ACC001,20] | 1 | 20 | 20 |
| [[ID002,ACC002,400], [ID002,ACC004,30]] | 2 | 430 | 215 |
| [ID003,ACC003,500] | 1 | 500 | 500 |

I tried using `ds.groupBy("accountID").agg(Map("balance" -> "avg"))`, however I am only able to use Map function to get the average. Need help to do multiple aggregation without using spark sql functions.

Appreciate any help to achieve the above solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution

```scala
val cust_data = Seq[(String, String, Int)](
("ID001",   "ACC001",   20),
("ID002",   "ACC002",   400),
("ID003",   "ACC003",   500),
("ID002",   "ACC004",   30)).toDF("customerID", "accountID",    "balance")

val out_df = cust_data.groupBy("customerID").agg(count($"accountID").alias("number_of_accounts"),
                                   sum($"balance").alias("totalBalance"),
                                   avg($"balance").alias("averageBalance"))

                                    
out_df.show()

+----------+------------------+------------+--------------+
|customerID|number_of_accounts|totalBalance|averageBalance|
+----------+------------------+------------+--------------+
|     ID001|                 1|          20|          20.0|
|     ID002|                 2|         430|         215.0|
|     ID003|                 1|         500|         500.0|
+----------+------------------+------------+--------------+
```